# Access a parent window control(e.g a Label) inside Child page

Tags: c#, wpf, window, frame

[image]I am developing a WPF application where i have a MainWindow that has a Frame control and a Label Control inside it, i have set the source of the Frame control to one of the pages i have created, what i want is to be able to change the content of Label control (inside Main window) from my Page.xaml which is displayed inside the Frame control.

Here is an Image to further illustrate what i really want . excuse my drawing!!

Comment: This is going to be pretty difficult to assess without some code. Could you please post an example which illustrates the problem?

Comment: I havent Written any Specific code : but i can tell the use case, for instance i want to do some operation inside the page and then display a message a relevant message inside the main windows Label control. e.g Record was added successfully or some error has occured.

Comment: Pass the main window to the child via the constructor

Comment: @Blam Can you please provide an example, i am a newbie in WPF.

Comment: `MainWindow main = new MainWindow(); 
 Label lblstats = (Label)main.FindName("lblStatus");
 lblstats.Content = "this text has come from AdminSite page!";`                              **I tried this code but it doesnt work**

Comment: Pass main to Page.xaml via the ctor of Page.xaml

Comment: I am opening the Page inside the frame as follows ` frameContent.Source = new Uri("Pages/New_Record.xaml", UriKind.Relative);`  now how can i pass anything in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Page page = new Page(this);  
Framme.Content = page;
```

Comment: My Frame is inside the MainWindow. and I am loading the page.xaml inside that Frame, and i want to change the content of the label which is also inside the mainWindow but i want to do this from my Page.xaml.cs , i am not sure i am following you.

Comment: What part of you pass MainWindow to Page in the ctor is not clear?  You than have a reference to MainWindow that you can manipulate.

Comment: Thanks alot i figure it out but i just wanted to ask you one more thing. whats the difference between setting the `frame.Content=page` and `frame.source=pageURI`